# Finding all lineage paths (non standard parent-child) from top level down using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, recursion, parent-child

I have been tasked with mapping the lineage of some datasets that we have.  I have been working on pulling together a script that can dynamically identify the lineage (top down) for a given starting dataset id.  These are a series of input/output datasets that are flowing through an ETL tool.  I have 2 datasets to work with, unfortunately these are both only available as CSVs...  There are well over 5000 starting points, so doing this manually isn't an option.  I have tried a variety of approaches, but haven't yet been able to find a solution that gets me all the way there.  I list what I have tried at the bottom of this question.

Data that I have available

1. Master Dataset List
2. Inputs/Outputs with DATAFLOW_IDS

Master Dataset List (csv)

```
abc, def, ghi, jkl, mno, pqr
```

Dataflow Inputs/Outputs with DATAFLOW_IDS

```
DATAFLOW_ID | NUMBER_OF_INPUTS | INPUT_IDS | NUMBER_OF_OUTPUTS | OUTPUT_IDS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1765A       | 1                |           | 1                 | abc
1765A       | 1                | def       | 1                 |
9999A       | 2                |           | 1                 | ghi
9999A       | 2                | jkl       | 1                 |
9999A       | 2                | mno       | 1                 |
9999B       | 1                |           | 1                 | mno
9999B       | 1                | pqr       | 1                 |
```

For example, starting at OUTPUT_ID [abc]...

```
 1. Find DATAFLOW_ID for starting OUTPUT_ID    | [abc] is in DATAFLOW_ID [1765A]
 2. Using that DATAFLOW_ID, find all INPUT_IDs | [def]
 3. The found INPUT_ID is now your new starting OUTPUT_ID.  Repeat steps 1,2 until no results found (base level reached).  Do this for all IDs listed in the Master Dataset List.
```

My goal is to get the output in the following format.

```
STARTING_ID | LEVEL_ID | DEPTH
------------------------------
abc         | abc      | 0
abc         | 1765A    | 1
abc         | def      | 2
def         | def      | 0
ghi         | ghi      | 0
ghi         | 9999A    | 1
ghi         | jkl      | 2
ghi         | mno      | 2
ghi         | 9999B    | 3
ghi         | pqr      | 4
jkl         | jkl      | 0
mno         | mno      | 0
mno         | 9999B    | 1
mno         | pqr      | 2
pqr         | pqr      | 0
```

What I have tried

- Dictionary, but doesn't work because duplicate keys can exist (9999A to jkl and mno).
- Played around with defaultdict()
  The issue I am running into is that when recursively iterating through, I am not sure how to dynamically split to search all possible paths, and then go to the bottom of that path.  For example, above if the starting point is ghi, I find 9999A, but then my script only pulls jkl, and not mno - and does not go to the base of that respective path.

A few important points

1. The same inputs can be tied to multiple outputs
2. Input Count/Output count isn't always the same (2 inputs can lead to 1 output, 1 input can lead to 3 outputs, etc)
3. There can be multiple paths to traverse
4. Not all outputs have a path to traverse.  Some are only 1 level deep.
5. The starting point will always be an OUTPUT_ID

My current code below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools


master_dataset_list = ['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr']

dataflow_mappings = pd.DataFrame({'DATAFLOW_ID' : ['1765A','1765A','9999A','9999A','9999A','9999B','9999B'],'NUMBER_OF_INPUTS': [1,1,2,2,2,1,1,],'INPUT_IDS': [np.nan,'def',np.nan,'jkl','mno',np.nan,'pqr'],'NUMBER_OF_OUTPUTS': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1],'OUTPUT_IDS':['abc',np.nan,'ghi',np.nan,np.nan,'mno',np.nan]})

base_in = dataflow_mappings[['DATAFLOW_ID','INPUT_IDS']]
base_in.dropna(inplace=True)
base_in.rename(columns={'INPUT_IDS':'RESULT','DATAFLOW_ID':'SEARCH'}, inplace=True)
base_out = dataflow_mappings[['OUTPUT_IDS','DATAFLOW_ID']]
base_out.dropna(inplace=True)
base_out.rename(columns={'OUTPUT_IDS':'SEARCH','DATAFLOW_ID':'RESULT'}, inplace=True)
combined = base_in.append(base_out)


def traverse(o, tree_types=(list, tuple)):
    if isinstance(o, tree_types):
        for value in o:
            for subvalue in traverse(value, tree_types):
                yield subvalue
    else:
        yield o

def generate_chain(start_list,search_df):
    master_start_list = []
    master_search_list = []
    master_result_list = []
    results_dict = {}

    for start in start_list:
        start_value = []
        search_list = []
        result_list = []
        result_set_length = 1

        while result_set_length > 0:
            result = list(search_df[search_df['SEARCH'] == start]['RESULT'])
            result_set_length = len(result)

            for value in traverse(result):
                start_value.append(start)
                search_list.append(start)
                result_list.append(value)
                start = value

        master_start_list.append(start_value)
        master_search_list.append(search_list)
        master_result_list.append(result_list)

    master_start_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(master_start_list))
    master_search_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(master_search_list))
    master_result_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(master_result_list))

    test_list1 = []
    test_list1.append(master_start_list)
    test_list1.append(master_search_list)
    test_list1.append(master_result_list)

    return test_list1

test = generate_chain(master_dataset_list,combined)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['BASE_ID'] = test[0]
df['ID'] = test[1]
df['RESULT'] = test[2]
df
```

Comment: The data structure you are describing that has multiple possible inputs/outputs to given location is a **network**, specifically a directed graph network.  I would look at using `networkx` to hold this data structure.  You have all of the pieces to construct it in your larger dataset and using the built in path tools in `networkx` you can find paths between nodes, and inspect lengths pretty easy.  Just look out for any loops in the network.

Comment: Thanks @JeffH, I spent some time trying out networkx, this afternoon, and was able to get about 75% of the way there.  The remaining 25% looks like it should be possible, just need to figure out the best way to account for loops and get the total lengths.  Any suggestions on those fronts?  Appreciate the help!

Comment: Tough question.  Does it surprise you that there are loops in the connections?  That seems very odd for “data flow” problems.  I think if you “find all paths” you can still pick shortest path.  Tough to decide without full problem descripttion.